# Filtrar los datos de una matriz mediante un rango

Tags: php

Necesito imprimir este array de valores "hora", pero colocando un rango entre una hora y otra, así como lo tengo imprime todo, desde la hora cero hasta la hora 3.

El primer array viene con las horas del 00:00 hasta 3:00, obvio que luego se completaría todas las 24 horas.

El segundo array le coloque unos valores de cada 5 minutos, básicamente lo que necesito es que solo me imprima desde determinada hora hasta otra hora seleccionada, por ejemplo, desde 1:00 a 3:00, solo en ese rango por ejemplo.

He intentado con la función range, `foreach (range(1, 3) as $horario)` pero solo me funciona con un array, con el array multidimensional no funciona.

```
$horario=array(
  "0"=>array(
      "0"=>"00:00",
      "1"=>"00:05",
      "2"=>"00:10",
      "3"=>"00:15"
  ),
  "1"=>array(
      "4"=>"1:00",
      "5"=>"1:05",
      "6"=>"1:10",
      "7"=>"1:15"
  ),
  "2"=>array(
      "8"=>"2:00",
      "9"=>"2:05",
      "10"=>"2:10",
      "11"=>"2:15"
  ),
  "3"=>array(
      "12"=>"3:00",
      "13"=>"3:05",
      "14"=>"3:10",
      "15"=>"3:15"
  )
);

foreach ( $horario as $hora=>$hora1){
    echo " $hora <br>";

    while (list($minutos,$minutos1)=each($hora1)){
        echo " $minutos1 <br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Los valores que muestras en tu matriz de datos no dejan de ser cadenas de texto dado lo cual solo podrías hacer comparaciones de igualdad pero no de intervalos
- Haría falta solamente que implementes 2 ciclos `foreach` que te permitirán llegar a cada uno de los valores de cada vector
- Puedes por fuera del ciclo declarar 2 variables, las cuales:

  - Se formatearán a una estructura de hora:minutos:segundos
  - Declaramos una variable por fuera de los ciclos, que posteriormente llenaremos con el valor de cada hora que nos da el segundo ciclo foreach el cual también podemos formatear a hora:minutos:segundos
- Ahora podemos construir un condicional en el cual evaluaremos: si la hora recuperada en cada iteración y que recién hemos formateado es mayor o igual y menor o igual a las 2 variables que establecimos como límites fuera de los ciclos

  - En caso de que sea cierta dicha condición nos retornará las horas entre ese intervalo que existen en toda la matriz

Código:

```
<?php

$horario=array(
  "0"=>array(
      "0"=>"00:00",
      "1"=>"00:05",
      "2"=>"00:10",
      "3"=>"00:15"
  ),
  "1"=>array(
      "4"=>"1:00",
      "5"=>"1:05",
      "6"=>"1:10",
      "7"=>"1:15"
  ),
  "2"=>array(
      "8"=>"2:00",
      "9"=>"2:05",
      "10"=>"2:10",
      "11"=>"2:15"
  ),
  "3"=>array(
      "12"=>"3:00",
      "13"=>"3:05",
      "14"=>"3:10",
      "15"=>"3:15"
  )
);

$nuevoFormato = '';
$inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", "01:00:00")->format("H:i:s");
$fin    = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", "03:00:00")->format("H:i:s");

foreach($horario as $grupo) {
    foreach($grupo as $hora) {
        $nuevoFormato = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $hora)->format("H:i:s");
        
        if($nuevoFormato >= $inicio && $nuevoFormato <= $fin) {
            echo $hora."-";
        }
    }
}
```

Con una salida así:

> 1:00-1:05-1:10-1:15-2:00-2:05-2:10-2:15-3:00-

- [Documentación de referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Excelente, Muchas gracias, llevaba 6 días quemando neuronas y no encontraba la solución, soy nuevo en esto, pero genial, muy agradecido.